# Turn on Ack in MacVIm

Tags: search, vim, macvim, ack

I'm new to MacVim and have installed Janus. I can't figure out how to search my project using Ack.vim.

For janus it says "Customizations: Janus rebinds command-shift-f () to bring up :Ack." But when I do command-shift-f I get this message:

```
The plugin ack is disabled for the following reason: The ack program is not installed
```

How do I use ack? If I have to install it, how do I do so? (guessing it has something to do with .vimrc or .vimrc.after but am not sure)

Thanks

Comment: Did you install the `ack` command? `Ack.vim` call external command `ack`.

Comment: I only installed Janus. Shouldn't Ack be included and turned on by default? Otherwise why list it for Janus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to install `ack` first - it is an external program:

Instructions for Mac OS can be found on the [ack-website](http://betterthangrep.com/install/) and require MacPorts or homebrew.

Comment: I have installed `ack` using MacPorts, which installs the binary `ack-5.12`. I have setup an alias `ack='ack-5.12'` but still MacVim refuses to brink `ack` up

Comment: I still get the same error on Vim, after followin the steps. I've even set the alias. I can run 'ack' on my shell.

Comment: You have to watch out where you put the `alias` definition: if you put in the `.bashrc` file it will not be available when you do not start MacVim from a command line, because `.bashrc` is not read at login time. You have to put the alias in the `.bash_profile` file (or if you use `zsh` into `.zprofile` I think). More info can be found at wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell#Configuration_files_for_shells

Answer (score 3):

Ack is an external program and Ack.vim is only an interface to Ack. You want that interface to Ack if you already use Ack: if you don't already have it on your machine you probably don't need it.

If you really need/want to use Ack, just [install](http://betterthangrep.com/install/) it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually getting the same thing here with MacVim combined with Janus.

if you open macvim via command-line 'mvim .' then ack is available. if you open via "open new macvim buffer here" ack is not available.

guessing path problems.

Comment: "mvim ." via command did not give access to Ack. Once I installed Ack I was good to go.